# How to delete all objects (rows) in Parse using c#

Tags: c#, parse-platform

Basically, I want to clear a table (or class as Parse names it) and then repopulate it with new values. Repopulation is not a issue, I cannot figure out how to delete all objects in the class.
I am coding in c#.
Edit: I have tried to accomplish this by

```
ParseObject question = new ParseObject("questions");  
await question.DeleteAsync();  
await question.SaveAsync();
```

I have also tried to grasp the query, but to no avail. I (think I) can run the query, but then I dont know how to perform the delete operation on the data.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>();  
await query.FindAsync();
```

Solved:

```
IEnumerable<ParseObject> query = await ParseObject.GetQuery(q_parse_table_name).WhereEqualTo(q_parse_column_qSet, qSetNo).FindAsync();
foreach (ParseObject po in query)
 await po.DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Please provide a good, complete, minimal piece of code to that shows how you are currently trying to do what you want. You could include a commented out section for the part you don't understand. Otherwise you're asking us to do a lot of research and coding.

Comment: I have tried 
  ParseObject question = new ParseObject("questions");
  await question.DeleteAsync();
  await question.SaveAsync();
and i have tried to grasp the query, but to no avail. I can run the query, but then I dont know how to perform the delete operation on the data.
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>();
  await query.FindAsync();

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Well the documentation is not very good but I can give the algorithmic steps that you can try. First, get all the objects using the query. Once you have got the objects, you can use the destroy method to delete all the data. Finally execute save method. Let me know if this works.

Edit: Try `await myObject.DeleteAsync();` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
public void Dispose() 
{ 
Finalize(); 
System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
} 


}
```